# SQLITE data query

Tags: android, sqlite

does anybody know why it doesn't work

```
 bd.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE date(date_start)=?",new String[]{"date('now')"});
```

I test it and I think the issue is that it doesn't recognize date('now') as a sqlite function, just as a string.

Can I work out this?

thanks

Comment: Using `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE date(date_start)=date(?)` and `"now"`  as argument?

Comment: Have you tried to do `SELECT date('now')` to see if your guess it correct? Besides, what's the actual name of the table? Cause you can't have a table called `table`.

Comment: that was OK, this walk around date(?) works fine!!! THANKS